# Snapshot Firebase return "<null>" in swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, snapshot

I'm trying to perform a query in Firebase, and convert the snapshot to array. But the few nodes in the snapshot give me a string like this:

```
"<null>"
```

Code:

```
Database.database().reference().child("users").child(myUser!.key).child("children").child(self.key).observe(.childChanged, with: { snapshot in
            if snapshot.value != nil {
                Children.updateDataChildren(children: self, values: [snapshot.key:snapshot.value!])
            }
        })
```

Output:

```
["birth": 1543406045721, "diaries": {
    diaryIndicator =     {
        2018 =         {
            10 =             (
                "<null>",
                                {
                    feeding = 1;
                }
            );
        };
    };
}, "name": Teste1]
```

Firebase:

[Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNGCl.png)

Comment: Can you show us the data in firebase

Comment: Bruno, please ask questions in english here. For questions in portuguese, there is a stackoverflow translated to portuguese (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/). Abraço fera!

Comment: @JeanPierre Firebase: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNGCl.png